# Best way to persist data bound GridView inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I have a `GridView` control inside `UpdatePanel` and a simple `TextBox`.

After text is entered into the `TextBox` (and a button is clicked), a result List is retrieved from the database and bound to the `GridView`.

```
        grd.DataSource = DataManager.GetFilteredList(txt.Text);
        grd.DataBind();
```

Every row returned has a `LinkButton` `TemplateField` column with a `CommandArgument` and `CommandName` parameter.

I want to run some code when that button is clicked but because the whole `Page` gets recreated even on partial postback the `GridView` loses its data. Normally I would pass necessary parameters inside query string but because this is insidide `UpdatePanel` I cannot do it.

What is a good and clean approach to this? Only thing that comes to my mind would be, instead of using `RowCommand`, to create the `GridView` button with a simple HTML `<a>` element, passing a query string parameter in its `HRef` parameter, then trigger a full postback and finally conducting the operation inside `Page_Load` event but this seems clunky.

Here's the requested ASP markup:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="input-group">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click">Search</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />
            <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"  ItemType="xxx.Policy" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" OnRowCommand="grd_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" CommandName="Connect" CommandArgument='<%#: Item.Id %>' runat="server">Connect</asp:LinkButton> 
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grd" EventName="RowCommand" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some of your ASP markup

Comment: I have added the markup. It's nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RowCommand` event

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Connect")
    {
        //Add your code to connect using Item.Id
        //get Item.Id value using e.CommandArgument.ToString()
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, it does not work. GridView loses its data when RowCommand is called.

Comment: try replacing with `<%# Bind("ItemId") %>` and `ItemId` is a field in your database